# How will I able to retrieve data from a table in my database and put it in a dropdownlist? JSP and MSSQL?

Tags: sql-server, jsp

1. Here is my Controller

   ```
   package ledger.controllers;
   import java.util.List;
   import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
   import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
   import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

   import ledger.dao.EmployeeDao;
   import ledger.model.EmployeeModel;



   @Controller
   public class EmployeeController {

       @Autowired
       EmployeeDao employeeDao;

       @RequestMapping(value = "employee/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
       public ModelAndView employeeAdd(@ModelAttribute("employee")EmployeeModel employee) {
           employeeDao.save(employee);
           return new ModelAndView("redirect:/employee");
       }

       @RequestMapping(value="employee/delete/{id}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
       public ModelAndView deleteEmployee(@PathVariable int id) {
           employeeDao.delete(id);
           return new ModelAndView("redirect:/employee");
       }

       @RequestMapping(value="employee/view",method = RequestMethod.GET)
       public ModelAndView view(@PathVariable int id){
           List<EmployeeModel> list = employeeDao.getEmployee();   
           ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
           mav.addObject("list",list);
           mav.addObject("Employee",new EmployeeController());
           mav.setViewName("Employee");
           return mav;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Here is my Dao

   ```
   package ledger.dao;

   import java.sql.ResultSet;
   import java.sql.SQLException;
   import java.util.List;

   import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
   import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;

   import ledger.model.EmployeeModel;
   import ledger.controllers.EmployeeController;

   public class EmployeeDao {

   JdbcTemplate template;

   public void setTemplate(JdbcTemplate template) {
       this.template = template;
   }

   public int save(EmployeeModel g) {
       String sql = "insert into TBL_EMPLOYEE (EMP_FNAME,EMP_MNAME,EMP_LNAME,EMP_AGE,EMP_CONTACTNUMBER,EMP_ADDRESS,EMP_EMAIL_ADDRESS) values('"+g.getEmp_fname()+"','"+g.getEmp_mname()+"','"+g.getEmp_lname()+"','"+g.getEmp_age()+"','"+g.getEmp_contact_number()+"','"+g.getEmp_address()+"','"+g.getEmp_email_address()+"')";
       return template.update(sql);
   }

   public int delete(int id) {
       String sql = "delete from TBL_EMPLOYEE where EMP_ID = "+id+"";
       return template.update(sql);
   }

   public List<EmployeeModel> getEmployee() {
       return template.query("select * from TBL_EMPLOYEE ", new RowMapper<EmployeeModel>(){
           public EmployeeModel mapRow(ResultSet rs, int row)  throws SQLException{
               EmployeeModel g = new EmployeeModel();
               g.setEmp_id(rs.getInt(1));
               g.setEmp_fname(rs.getString(2));
               g.setEmp_mname(rs.getString(3));
               g.setEmp_lname(rs.getString(4));
               g.setEmp_age(rs.getInt(5));
               g.setEmp_contact_number(rs.getInt(6));
               g.setEmp_address(rs.getString(7));
               g.setEmp_email_address(rs.getString(8));


               return g;
           }
       });
   }




   }
   ```
3. Here is my Model

   ```
   package ledger.model;

   import java.util.List;

   public class EmployeeModel {

   private int emp_id; 
   private String  emp_fname;
   private String  emp_mname;
   private String  emp_lname;
   private int emp_age;
   private int emp_contact_number;
   private String emp_address;
   private String emp_email_address;

   public int getEmp_id() {
       return emp_id;
   }
   public void setEmp_id(int emp_id) {
       this.emp_id = emp_id;
   }
   public String getEmp_fname() {
       return emp_fname;
   }
   public void setEmp_fname(String emp_fname) {
       this.emp_fname = emp_fname;
   }
   public String getEmp_mname() {
       return emp_mname;
   }
   public void setEmp_mname(String emp_mname) {
       this.emp_mname = emp_mname;
   }
   public String getEmp_lname() {
       return emp_lname;
   }
   public void setEmp_lname(String emp_lname) {
       this.emp_lname = emp_lname;
   }
   public int getEmp_age() {
       return emp_age;
   }
   public void setEmp_age(int emp_age) {
       this.emp_age = emp_age;
   }
   public int getEmp_contact_number() {
       return emp_contact_number;
   }
   public void setEmp_contact_number(int emp_contact_number) {
       this.emp_contact_number = emp_contact_number;
   }
   public String getEmp_address() {
       return emp_address;
   }
   public void setEmp_address(String emp_address) {
       this.emp_address = emp_address;
   }
   public String getEmp_email_address() {
       return emp_email_address;
   }
   public void setEmp_email_address(String emp_email_address) {
       this.emp_email_address = emp_email_address;
   }

   }
   ```

Comment: Where's your page and code behind that?

Comment: http://www.datafilehost.com/d/1693ff80

Comment: Please post the code.

Comment: Cant post anymore

Comment: Sample scripts formated